# Word or phrase for multilingual pun/word play

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

The question is about multilingual jokes or puns, and if there is a word for them in English. Some examples:

A German-English friend sometimes says *Senkfuss* instead of “thank you.” *Senkfuss* means “flat foot” in German, but the joke is that it sounds a little like “thank you” said with a German accent.

A French-English family I used to know would say “quel smell!” The French *quel* and the English “smell” rhyme, and put together, if you understand both languages, they mean “what a smell!”

In [this documentary](http://www.truewestfilms.com/completed-films/remember-memory/), Hélène Cixous describes how her non-German-speaking father used to say in French, *en dessous du bras* (“under the arm”) in reply to a question to which he did not know the answer. Under the arm, you would find *Schweiss* (sweat in German), which to HC’s father’s untrained ear, might have sounded like the German *Ich weiss nicht* (I don’t know).

There are thousands of these jokes that require a knowledge of two or more languages to make sense. In my observation they tend to arise within families or small communities where the knowledge of multiple languages is shared.

Is there a name in English for this kind of multilingual word play? I Googled “multilingual puns” and “multilingual word games” without a lot of success, neither in finding a more concise or descriptive term or phrase, nor in actually finding more of what I’m talking about.

(I know extra questions are discouraged -- and this part'll get shot down for being off-topic -- but if anyone knows of any sites where these jokes are shared, I would be very much indebted to you if you could leave the addresses in the comments!).

Comment: You might try searching for "bilingual wordplay" instead of "multilingual." You will see such links [as this.](http://brave-new-words.blogspot.com/2007/07/bilingual-wordplay.html) Actually, there are usually only two languages involved in these types of jokes.

Comment: That's interesting- when I was in high school French class we would say "*Good idea!*" which translated into French as "*bonne idée*" which sounded like "*bunny day"* which we then translated into French to be "*jour lapin*"

Comment: The French eat a small breakfast. They believe one egg is *un oeuf*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Interlingual pun* seems to be quite common in [*Google* search results](http://www.google.com/search?q=interlingual%20pun).

Comment: Would downvoter most kindly offer a constructive suggestion for improving the answer?